# Как влияет виджет комментариев на поисковую раздачу страницы?

Tags: javascript, seo, виджет

Предположим у меня есть сайт со страницами, куда заходят пользователи, переходя из гугла и яндекса. Предположим, я к страницам прикручу виджет комментариев `facebook`, `vk`, `twitter` и прочих социальных сетей, типо такого:

```
    <!--Здесь просто код виджета вконтакте -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://vk.com/js/api/openapi.js?157"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  VK.init({apiId: API_ID, onlyWidgets: true});
</script>

<!-- Put this div tag to the place, where the Comments block will be -->
<div id="vk_comments"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
VK.Widgets.Comments("vk_comments", {limit: 10, attach: "*"});
</script>
```

Как вы считаете, от этого деяния повысится, понизится или не изменится рейтинг страницы в поисковой выдаче?

Comment: Чем больше ссылок на сторонние ресурсы, тем поисковик менее лоялен.

Comment: Это и мне понятно. Комментарии со ссылками будем отбраковывать. Предположим нет комментов, а в моём понимании, виджет - это тоже ссылка на сайт. Понизится ли страница в раздаче после этого?